# Entity Framework Fluent API: Composite key -> Circular relationships

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

There are 3 tables:

- The Parent (Parents)
- Child (Children)
- The transition of one child to another (Jump)

For example imagine book. Is the book itself, it will be table Parents. The book has pages, Children. On the pages there are footnotes-the links to other pages, it Jumps.

For Children I use a composite key (new {ChildId, ParentId}), since by analogy with books, page 1 is found in various books. In the real world the ID of the string, it contains a code.

Table Jumps. it describes a footnote. The page ID which will transition (SourceChildId) and the page ID which will be the transition (TargetChildId). Since the transition occurs within the same book(Parent) that uses one field for both key — ParentId.

I thought this structure to be logical, until I tried to Udpdate-Database command, i get an exception: "Circular relationships with referential integrity constraints detected."
This ring makes a reference to my favorite table Jumps... I really like their lokalitetu, but....

Please help me to simulate the model data for CodeFirst for this task(analogy with books, pages and pages of footnotes). Test project attached.

Visual Studio project. ~10mb. google drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Je5INk3Cy2bXdfWHZSTm1lUms

Best wishes,
Sergey

Comment: i think this problem cause
Jump.ParentId and
Jump.Source.ParentId

can(teoreticaly) be not same...
can set up by flyent API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.
2 changes.

1) get off from Jump object references, leave only properties. Set up fluent Api like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasMany(x => x.JumpsFrom).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => new { x.SourceId, x.ParentId });
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasMany(x => x.JumpsTo).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => new { x.TargetId, x.ParentId });
```

2) In to Seed() before setting Parent.FirstChildId i was call context.SaveChanges()

Solved issue project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Je5INk3Cy2aTB4ZVNBZEVfbEE